# check if there is at least a single true value in SparseBooleanArray

Tags: java, android, sparse-array

I'm creating an Android app with a `ListView` and I'm using this line:

```
SparseBooleanArray checkedPositions = list.getCheckedItemPositions();
```

Then I want to iterate over the array but only if there is at least a single value which is true in the `checkedPositions` array.

Can something like this be done?

Comment: Is this helpful http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemCount() ?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that. But what you could do is to create another method which does that for you.

```
public boolean containsTrueValue(SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray) {
    boolean containsBoolean = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < sparseBooleanArray.size(); i++) {
        if (sparseBooleanArray.valueAt(i) == true) {
            containsBoolean = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return containsBoolean;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`ListView` has a `getCheckedItemCount()`, so rather than checking your `SparseBooleanArray` you could work it out from your `ListView`. So, you could check:

```
list.getCheckedItemCount() > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList class in Java have method contains. You can cast your list to arrayList and use this method. Example:

```
ArrayList<Boolean> array = new ArrayList();

        array.add(false);
        array.add(false);
        array.add(false);
        array.add(true);
        array.add(false);
        array.add(false);

        boolean contains = array.contains(true);
```

contains variable will be true if you execute this code.

Comment: and yet the question is about SparseBooleanArray and not about ArrayList